# Using Azure Storage Safely in an Electron Application

Tags: azure, electron, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm building a video sharing application for recording and sharing gaming clips. I've recently added cloud storage as a feature where I am using the Azure SDK for Node to interact with a storage account where videos and metadata are uploaded. It all works nicely so far. My goal is to sell the cloud hosting feature for a small monthly subscription.

The electron client takes a storage account name and access key. It has free reign over the storage account and can upload as much as it likes with no limit. That scares me as I don't want to get hit with a big Azure bill.

I assumed there would be controls in Azure to create less privileges storage accounts and/or containers with size limits imposed. However, none of that seems to exist.

So my question; how can I safely distribute credentials to my users that allow for limiting reading and writing to an Azure storage account?

It seems like I could setup an authentication server that acts as a proxy for every request to my Azure storage account using the signing mechanisms in Azure, but it feels like that's overcomplicating what seems to be a basic use case? If there is no neat solution, do other cloud providers offer something suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The electron client takes a storage account name and access key. It
> has free reign over the storage account and can upload as much as it
> likes with no limit. That scares me as I don't want to get hit with a
> big Azure bill.

You are correct in your understanding. Not only account key gives complete control over a storage account it also creates a big challenge if you were to replace the account key for some reason (all of your users would need to download a new version of the application.

> I assumed there would be controls in Azure to create less privileges
> storage accounts and/or containers with size limits imposed. However,
> none of that seems to exist.

That's correct. It is not possible to create less privileged accounts or impose size restrictions on containers out of the box. This is something you would need to handle on your own.

> So my question; how can I safely distribute credentials to my users
> that allow for limiting reading and writing to an Azure storage
> account?

Please look into [`Shared Access Signature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature) feature of Azure Storage. It allows you to create SAS URLs that give the users time-bound, permission-restricted access to your Storage Account.

You would still need to implement a proxy. The responsibility of this proxy would be to generate SAS tokens. Depending on the control and security you want, you can implement this proxy in two ways:

1. **Control upload through this proxy**: Basically your users would always have to go through this proxy. When they try to upload something, they would be sending the content to your proxy first. The content will get validated and from there it will be written to Azure Storage.

The downside of this approach is that everything gets routed through this proxy and you may need a much robust infrastructure to handle user's requests but it is much secure and gives you a lot of control.

2. **Use proxy for generating SAS tokens**: You can use this proxy to generate just the SAS tokens. The way it would work is that when the user tries to upload something in your application, you would send that data's metadata (e.g. file name, file type, size etc.) and you would do some validation (e.g. the size does not exceed prescribed limits or the file type is that of a supported type etc.). Once the validation is successful, you would generate a SAS URL and send that back to your application. If the validation fails, you return an error instead. Your application code would then use this SAS URL to directly upload the content in Azure Storage.

However, please keep in mind that SAS URLs can be misused. For example, they can send you the information about a small sized file, get the SAS URL and somehow use that URL to upload some other file. You would need to protect your application against such use cases.

You may find this link helpful regarding best practices when using SAS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#best-practices-when-using-sas.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Having a proxy that all uploads pass through sounds like it would work well but is probably too much infrastructure for my project.

The other option sounds good. The bit I was missing here is the ability to generate a SAS token that is specific for a file size. I couldn't find anything in the docs to support this  being a thing, but I'll have a go with the SDK. 

I had assumed that the SAS URL would just say "here's a URL that you have permission to upload to for the next hour" and there would be nothing to stop a malicious 1PB upload.

Comment: Hm actually, according to your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902354/is-there-azure-sas-storage-restrictions-by-content-type-and-size it is not possible to include the restriction by size in the SAS URL.

Comment: `it is not possible to include the restriction by size in the SAS URL` - That is still the case. Sorry, if I was not clear in my answer. What I mean to say is when you receive the metadata (which would contain the size of the file) in your proxy layer, you can check the size of the file and return an error back to the user if the file they are trying to upload is more than allowed size. But yes, it can still be misused.

Comment: Misused in the sense that they may send information about a small file, get the token from you and use that token to upload a large file. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: That's a shame, it would have been a really neat solution without introducing more complication. Regardless, thanks for the excellent answer.